# Is there a binary function f(x,y) where x,y are integers and result is 0 or 1, and result 1 in 2d plane are "continous" and "irregular" enough

Tags: algorithm

That is, if f(x,y)=1, then f(x-1,y),f(x+1,y),f(x,y-1),f(x,y+1) at least one results 1.

I'm thinking about a technology to define game map, neither predefined nor random generated each time, but bind to 2d binary function, so the map data will never be saved to disk and each time entering game, the map keeps the same.

If 1 means land and 0 means ocean, I want the lands keep continous, all are reachable, no islands, and of course, the map must be enough irregular.
I'm not good at maths, is it possible? thanks.

What I need is only a simple function, no recursions, eg. once xy is given, the result is out, which has nothing to do with other values, only xy.

Comment: Why is javascript and c tagged?

Comment: What you're looking for is "procedural noise" as in [Perlin Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

Comment: Do you really need a single mathematical function? Using one of many existing terrain generation algorithms with a fixed seed should be sufficient to produce reproducible maps without having to store more than the seed.

Comment: There are many, here is one such function: `f(x,y)=1` here is another: `f(x,y)=(x==0 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: I tagged c and js because maybe there are some bitwise algorithm?

Comment: Don't just slap down random tags. Tag with the **specific language you are actually using for real code**. Either C or JavaScript is fine. Both is suggesting you have no idea what you're doing, or that you just don't care. Either way, not a good look.

Comment: @tadman gradients is not necessary to me, and I need each time the map keeps the same, so random generator is not suitable.

Comment: There are many simple functions for which your stated requirement is true, but none of those will do what you want, ie create a game map with all those extra conditions. Have a look at various open source games that create "random" maps. They use a seed value to make it appear random, but the functions are entirely deterministic and create the same map when given the same seed value. Examples that spring to mind: freeciv, openttd.

Comment: @EmanuelP Deterministic is just what i need, and irregular 0/1 squares maybe simple to achieve, but "continous" is hard to me.

Comment: @SandJX The way Freeciv does it is (oversimplified): pick a starting coordinate and then use different fractals to generate a "continent" from there.

Comment: You didn't read that example. Perlin Noise is exactly what you need. You use this as a basis for other calculations. While it is "random" it is **deterministic**, as in you will get *exactly* the same result each time given the same inputs. You can work this into other solutions using clamping or gating.

Answer (score 1):

Guaranteeing connectivity with local considerations only is a very strong constraint on what we can do. I agree with the comments that suggest traditional map generation from a fixed seed.

Nevertheless, to answer the question as framed, my first thought would be [star-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon) land. This idea requires a continuous function `f(θ) > 0` with period `2π`. We take every point `(x, y)` such that `hypot(x, y) < f(atan2(y, x))`.

This works great if `x` and `y` are real numbers -- every `(x, y)` in the land is connected by a straight line segment back to the origin `(0, 0)`, hence "star-shaped". Over the integers, we have to put an extra condition on `f`: the function `log(f(θ))` should be Lipschitz continuous (can't wiggle too much).

(You can skip this paragraph.) Assume without loss of generality that `x > 0` and `y > 0` are integers. If `(x, y)` is land, then we need `(x-1, y)` or `(x, y-1)` to be land. On one hand, one of these squares is closer, which is good since we're using a threshold: `min(hypot(y, x-1), hypot(y-1, x)) <= hypot(y, x) - (sqrt(2) - 1)`, which is tight for `(x, y) = (1, 1)`. On the other hand, the angle changes. We've deviated from the line segment by distance at most `1/sqrt(2)`. Let `r = hypot(x, y)`. The change in angle is at most `1/sqrt(2) / (r - 1/sqrt(2))`, which since `r >= sqrt(2)` is at most `1/sqrt(2) / (r - r/2) == sqrt(2) / r`. Therefore a Lipschitz constant of `(sqrt(2) - 1) / sqrt(2) = 1 - 1/sqrt(2)` should suffice (probably this can be tightened).

So far this is very abstract. The classic way to get a periodic function that doesn't wiggle too much is by adding sine waves (with varying phases). I've provided a Python implementation and sample output below. The land is not 100% guaranteed to be connected, but it should be extremely unlikely.

```
import math
import os
import random


def make_parameters(n=20):
    return [
        (random.random() / (i + 1), 2 * math.pi * random.random()) for i in range(n)
    ]


width = 100


def is_land(parameters, x, y):
    if (x, y) == (0, 0):
        return True
    theta = math.atan2(y, x)
    return math.hypot(x, y) < 0.1 * width * math.exp(
        sum(
            amp * math.sin((i + 1) * theta + phase)
            for i, (amp, phase) in enumerate(parameters)
        )
    )


def main():
    dir = "lands"
    os.mkdir(dir)
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            with open(os.path.join(dir, "%02d_%02d.pbm" % (i, j)), "w") as f:
                parameters = make_parameters()
                x0 = y0 = width // 2
                print("P1", file=f)
                print(width, width, file=f)
                for y in range(width):
                    print(
                        *(
                            int(is_land(parameters, x - x0, y - y0))
                            for x in range(width)
                        ),
                        file=f
                    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]